# Why is prior probability high for low degree polynomial

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayes-theorem

I am reading a text which is described below.

> Supervised learning can be done by choosing a hypothesis $h*$ that is most probable given the data :
> $h* = \underset{h \in H} {argmax}P(h | data)$.
>
> By Bayes rule,
> $h* = \underset{h \in H} {argmax} P(data | h)P(h)$.
> Then we can say that the prior probability $P(h)$ is high for a degree-1 or 2 polynomial, lower for a degree-7 polynomial

I did not understand why $P(h)$is high for degree-1 polynomial as compared to degree-7 polynomial.

Comment: In a hand-waving sense, each step-up in dimension increases the possibilities for the hypotheses and so reduces the prior probability (density, whatever) of an individual hypothesis in that higher dimension.

Comment: @Henry , So is this like as the dimension increases the number of coefficients increases. Thus, more possible polynomials. In a degree-1 suppose number of polynomials is n. Then,in a degree-7 we get 6 more coefficients, it'll be 7n. Probability of getting a particular polynomial is 1/n in degree-1. In degree 7 it is 1/7n which is less than degree-1. Intuitively is that correct understaning ? Please ignore the mathematical formality

Comment: In your example of $n$ possible values for each coefficient (and the intercept) your degree-7 polynomial allows $n^8$ possibilities while the degree-1 polynomial allows $n^2$.  In reality coefficients usually take real values, so you cannot push the analogy too far

Comment: @Henry Got it. Thanks